# jQuery filtering a close element using multiple checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, filtering

I need a solution for filtering a group of items with multiple checkboxes. I found a fiddle and modified it to my needs for testing purposes:

[`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/xvLotpd4/19)

Before it was based on "data-category" but I need it to be based on classes. Works just fine but there is one thing that I can't figure out myself. When filtering I don't want the actual element having the class (.red, .small, .africa) to hide or show but actually an element that it is nested in, I named it ".test" in my example and made it a div.

I think you can somehow do this using .closest('.test') but I don't know where to put it exactly.

[closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Can you help me with this? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: try `$('.flower').closest(".test").hide().end().filter($filteredResults).closest(".test").show();`

Comment: Thank you my friend! That was exactly what I was looking for. :) Had to add a .test <div> around all of the .flower items from that Fiddle but that is basically how it will be in my actual code since the items will all be nested in divs with the same class. Works like a charm. :)

Comment: I'm glad it helps ..  Have a great day :-)